# How can I use the Branches API endpoint to selectively remove branch protection

Tags: github-api

If I have a branch protection rule configured as:

dev*

and I have 3 branches:

dev_foo1
dev_foo2
dev_foo3

all matching that rule, and now I want to delete the *dev_foo2* branch, the only way to do that is to first delete that branch protection rule, then delete the branch, then reapply the rule. That process is very broken, IMO anyhow.

According to the API doc, this should remove branch protection from 'dev_foo2':

**DELETE /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/dev_foo2/protection**

but it does not. It does not return an error, but it also does not remove or disable branch protection for that branch.

Is this due to the wildcard regex perhaps?

Is there a way to remove or disable the branch protection for a specific branch through the API using any other endpoint, for example?

Thanks in advance!